# How to initialize spring boot to project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring boot. When I'm trying to initialize spring boot using intellij idea, It shows this error.

[image: Spring boot initialization erro][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLDW2.png)

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v4S6K.png)

How can I fix it?
**I used Spring web, spring data mongodb, lombok and spring boot devtools dependencies.**

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could find the solution for this problem. These are the steps that I followed.

1. I delete the existing MongoDB dependency.
2. Then I copied high usage MongoDB dependency version from MVNRepository.
3. Then I added that copied dependency to the project.

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed this Error with this solutions:

1. Clean Project
2. Delete MongoDb Dependency
3. Copy high usage MongoDB dependency version from Repository
4. Add to project Copied dependency